# How do I create a Jhipster relationship between an entity and two other entities using the same field?

Tags: jpa, frontend, relationship, jhipster, entities

I have three entities;
`entity DamagedItems { }, entity Recipe { }, entity RawProduct { }.`

In a scenario where the DamagedItems should capture both Recipes and RawMaterial in one field, let's say damagedItemName, how do you relate these three entities using damegedItemName without creating identifier conflict?

```
   `//this is what I want to achieve
    relationship OnetoOne{
    DamagedItems {damagedItemName} to Recipe,
    DamagedItems {damagedItemName} to RawProduct
     }`
```

Creating the entities this way has resulted to identifier conflict

Answer (score 0):

You can't model polymorphic relationships with JDL. You have to code it manually probably using inheritance.